# is there something like buffer-numbering-mode?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I am looking for something like window-numbering but to changing among buffers, specifically for tabbar, but I think something generic may be used. Any idea?

Comment: Could you please elaborate and maybe give an example?

Comment: http://tapoueh.org/blog/2010/07/25-dim-switch-windowel.html

Comment: I am talking about the typical way to change among tabs with keyboard, usually alt-<number>.  
I have resolved this taking part of the default configuration for aquamacs [1]. I put all my tabbar configuration preferences here [2] if somebody wants to try. Better faces and behaviour, Enjoy.
--- 
  [1]: https://github.com/dholm/tabbar/blob/master/aquamacs-tabbar.el   
  [2]: https://bitbucket.org/arco_group/arco-emacs/src/tip/config/tabbar.cfg.el

Answer (score 3):

I think, that use of [iswitchb](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers) or [ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) could be much more handy than using numbers, especially when working with dozens of buffers. Anyway, I recommend to look to [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SwitchingBuffers) on emacswiki